# Remove trailing zeros from byte[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I'm working with TCP protocol and read from socket and write the data to a byte[] array.
Here is a example of my data:

```
94 39 E5 D9 32 83
D8 5D 4C B1 CB 99 
08 00 45 00 00 98 
41 9F 40 00 6C 06 
9C 46 26 50 48 7D 
C0 A8 01 05 03 28
```

I created a byte[] array with size of 1024. Now I use this method to remove null indexes from it:

```
public void Decode(byte[] packet)
{
    byte[] temp;
    int c = 0;
    foreach(byte x in packet)
        if (x != 0)
            c++;
    temp = new byte[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        temp[i] = packet[i];
    MessageBox.Show(temp.Length.ToString());
}
```

But it removes also 0x00 indexes that it maybe useful data...
How can I remove the 0s that are not wrapped with non-zero data (trailing 0s)?

Comment: How can you tell whether a zero is "useful" or not?

Comment: what do you mean with null indices ?

Comment: @harold because the order is very important for me...

Comment: or in other terms: give an example of what should be removed from the array ...

Comment: @Marc The data will get for example 104 byte from array. after the last byte, all of array indexes are null...

Comment: An index cannot be null in an array. Neither the value because `byte` is a value type. Do you want to remove 0x00 values from the array?

Comment: you mean you're getting an array with first 104 filled with data and the size of the array is bigger than 104 meaning the remaining items in the array have value 0 ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov No, I want to keep 0x00 values in center of array but remove any 0x00 value from end of tcp data that a got from the socket...

Comment: @Marc Exactly yes, I mean that

Comment: so I suppose what you want to do is tho shrink the size of the array to "throw out" all default 0 values and to fit the array size to the first 104 items.

Comment: @Mac Yes , Exactly ... How can do this?

Comment: When your byte[] is filled, you should get a value somewhere telling you how many bytes were read (this is currently likely a return value from a `Read` method that is being ignored).  You should use this to resize your array instead of just trimming 0's from the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should fix the code that's reading from the TCP socket so that you don't read something that you intend to throw away afterwards. It seems like a waste to me.

But to answer your question you could start counting in reverse order until you encounter a non-zero byte. Once you have determined the index of this non-zero byte, simply copy from the source array to the target array:

```
public byte[] Decode(byte[] packet)
{
    var i = packet.Length - 1;
    while(packet[i] == 0)
    {
        --i;
    }
    var temp = new byte[i + 1];
    Array.Copy(packet, temp, i + 1);
    MessageBox.Show(temp.Length.ToString());
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This is quite short and fast function to trim trailing zeroes from array.

```
public static byte[] TrimEnd(byte[] array)
{
    int lastIndex = Array.FindLastIndex(array, b => b != 0);

    Array.Resize(ref array, lastIndex + 1);

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a nice one line solution pure LINQ :

```
    public static byte[] TrimTailingZeros(this byte[] arr)
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Length == 0)
            return arr;
        return arr.Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x == 0).Reverse().ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Nice one-liner, good for simple test code. I wonder how well it performs though, are the `Reverse()` calls heavy?

Answer (score 1):

As you can't shrink the size of an array by definition you would have to use a dynamic data structure instead.

Use a List for example

```
List<byte> byteList;
```

Iterate over your byte array and add each value != 0 to the byteList. When you have reached the end of data in your byteArray break the iteration and discard the array and use the byteList from now on.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= byteArray.Length; i++) {

    if (byteArray[i] != 0) {

        byteList.Add(byteArray[i]);
    } else {

         break;
    }

}
```

If you though want to use an array you can create one directly from your list

```
byte[] newByteArray = byteList.ToArray();
```

Comment: This will stop at the first 0 byte and could potentially trim non-zero bytes afterwards. The OP wants to remove only consecutive zero bytes at the end of the array.

Comment: of course you're right :) But I won't delete the post maybe it gives him an idea how to use a List ..

Answer (score 0):

So you want to trim the `0x00`s at the end and copy it into a new array? That would be:

```
int endIndex = packet.Length - 1;
while (endIndex >= 0 && packet[endIndex] == 0)
    endIndex--;

byte[] result = new byte[endIndex + 1];
Array.Copy(packet, 0, result, 0, endIndex + 1);
```

Although of course probably there can be somehow valid `0x00`s at the end too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually very close example was given on MSDN site. Really C# 4.5 style - with `Predicate<T>`. You can try it if you want (although correct answer was already submitted)

[MSDN: Predicate Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx)

P.S. I'm still waiting for Linq style answer with `Select()` and `.ToList<byte[]>()` at end

Answer (score 0):

```
Byte[] b = new Byte[1024]; // Array of 1024 bytes

List<byte> byteList; // List<T> of bytes

// TODO: Receive bytes from TcpSocket into b

foreach(var val in b) // Step through each byte in b
{

    if(val != '0') // Your condition
    {
    }
    else
    {
        bytelist.Add(val); //Add the byte to the List
    }
}
bytelist.ToArray(); // Convert the List to an array of bytes
```