# Sending Protocol Buffered object in .Net ApiController to protobuf.js

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I am trying to use Proto-buf c# library in .net.  I am using an ApiController and the System.Net.WebSockets namespace.  It has a way of getting an incoming message.

```
ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
```

I need a stream to use protobuf.  I am not sure how to get one with this namespace since it is using an ArraySegment.
I was able to send a proto-buf object to decode/protobuf.js, but now have constructed an object on the js client and am sending to the server.

Example cust = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(result, PrefixStyle.Base128);

Comment: It's not clear whether the problem is *sending* back to the client (as per your title) or *receiving* from the client (as per the body). Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a `Stream` to deserialize from, you can use:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
```

`ArraySegment<byte>` is already wrapping a `byte[]`, so you just need to create a `MemoryStream` wrapping the same byte array, with the right offset and length.

Comment: How do I know how big to make the ArraySegment    ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);   I created a brand new project with my sample can cleared out alot of stuff now I get “Invalid field in source data: 0”

Comment: @magister: That sounds like a different problem to me - and one where we don't really have enough information to let you know. (And I don't know enough about web sockets to know whether they need to be treated as streams, or whether they're already message-oriented.)

Comment: yes I reverted back to protobuf-net 2.0.0.480  since my new project had the latest from nuget protobuf-net 2.0.0.668 (latest stable).  And the object doesn't deserialize.  I think think it is about buffer size or something.

Comment: @magister: Well that sounds like you should put some work into diagnosing it - look at the serialized size in the Javascript, look at what `result.Count` is in .NET, etc. I can't really help with a diagnosis as vague as "I think it is about buffer size or something"

Comment: well I will have to try and get more info.  I don't use buffers and streams too much, I just see an array of bytes in the watchlist, so I don't really know whats in there.  I also think perhaps the System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket.ReceiveAsync is too highly abstracted, should probably use TcpClient.GetStream() especially if my protocol objects get big

Comment: I pushed the sample onto github here https://github.com/cataquil/CSharpWebSocketProtoBuf  I am going to continue to find out why

Comment: it works if I use ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[69]);  but what is the message is a different size

Comment: @magister: *You need to work it out*. Look at whether WebSockets are stream based or message based; work out what happens if you specify a large buffer (e.g. the 1K that you're specifying now). Just occasional snippets of information aren't helpful.

Comment: It works if I set the ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[69]), but I don't know what to do to resize it for different messages

Comment: But you still haven't said what diagnostic steps you've taken to see what happens when the buffer is larger than it needs to be.

Comment: yeah I haven't worked out what to do yet.  I guess I have to create a 2nd ArraySegment<byte> based on where the index of position in the array where the Zeros start, then use that to populate a new ArraySegment.  I just don't know why the stream has been abstracted away in AspNetWebSocketContext and I have to even use this ArraySegment.

Comment: I cut the trailing zeros out of the byte[] after AspNetWebSocket loads the ArraySegment with the incoming buffer.  Then I use this to cut off the tailing zeros http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263297/remove-trailing-zeros-from-byte  Still if the original ArraySegment allocates 1kilobyte is the incoming protocol buffer object graph is big and goes over this limit then there will still be a problem.  Need to get async to wait for the entire stream.  I should be able to shove MBs in there and get dynamic resize.

Comment: @magister: If you're trying to send multiple messages over the same connection, you should length-prefix each message (e.g. with `WriteDelimitedTo` in the new API; I can't remember whether that's in the old API). You may need to make multiple `Read` calls... you could first read the length, then read just that much data.