# BitConverter return wrong bytes?

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert values to byte arrays.

For example, I have:

```
var b1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x85);
var b2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(12345);
```

The value of `b1` is:

```
{byte[4]}
    [0]: 133
    [1]: 0
    [2]: 0
    [3]: 0
```

And of `b2`:

```
{byte[4]}
    [0]: 57
    [1]: 48
    [2]: 0
    [3]: 0
```

Why does the byte array always have a size of 4? And is it possible to return the correct number of bytes (ie. excluding trailing 0's)?

Comment: [Integer Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) are always `int`s or `long`s (or unsigned variants)

Comment: What results did you _expect_?

Comment: `0x85` is still an `Int32`, not a `byte` if that's whats tripping you up

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11263512/579895) could help you...

Comment: Here is a cheat sheet http://www.eitworld.com/cpp/cp7.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four bytes *is* the correct number of bytes for a 32-bit integer. If you want it truncated to the minimum number of bytes necessary to represent a number, you'd have to do so yourself. There are actually very few applications for what you're looking for. `BitConverter` is for getting at the exact memory representation of certain primitive types. Something that is helpful for binary file formats or network protocols. For those things you usually want to get the same length for a result, which is based on the type you passed in.

Side note: Would you want `0` to result in an empty array? What about `-1`? Should that be `new byte [] { 255 }` or `new byte [] { 255, 255, 255, 255 }`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Granted, and edited :-) (I'd still think fixed-length things are way more common, and also have way less variability in how they are written/interpreted (remembering a few bugs in Flash regarding AMF ...)).

Comment: Why does `BitConverter.GetBytes((byte)0x85)` return a bytes array or 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono - because there isn't an overload of `GetBytes` that accepts a single byte parameter (why would you need one - what code would you expect it to run, beside just returning its input?)

Answer (score 1):

you are passing an `int` which has 32bits. You could pass a `short` and you would get 2 bytes instead:

```
var b1 = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)0x85);
var b2 = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)12345);
```

Comment: I have the vague feeling that they would want three bytes for values that fit in three bytes, which is where this method no longer works.

Comment: @Joey oh ok, that could indeed be the intention. I upvoted your answer which is way better,