# How to convert an int to a byte array of size 3?

Tags: c#

I need to convert an int to a byte array of size 3. This means dropping the last byte, for example:

```
var temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(myNum).Take(3).ToArray());
```

However, is there a better way to do is? Maybe by creating a custom struct?

**EDIT**

For this requirement I have a predefined max value of 16777215 for this new data type.

Comment: You can't encode all the possible values of an `int` in C# into just 3 bytes, so you're going to have to lose 8 bits either way, dropping "the last byte" seems every bit as good as an alternative, or did your question for a "better way" ask if there's a way to avoid dropping bits at all? Please clarify how you would judge if an alternate solution is better or worse than just "dropping the last byte".

Comment: Better way of doing it than what? I don't see any code nor I see an explanation of what you are trying to achieve so it's quite impossible to tell you what is the best way to implement that.

Comment: This is effectively a follow-up question to [their earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39891887/73070)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (no *Linq*, just getting bytes)

```
  int value = 123;

  byte[] result = new byte[] {
    (byte) (value & 0xFF),
    (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xFF),
    (byte) ((value >> 16) & 0xFF),
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a new `struct` that represents a 3 byte unsigned integer (based solely on the max value quoted).

Using your original method is very prone to failure, firstly, `Take(3)` is dependent on whether the system you're running on is big-endian or little-endian, secondly, it doesn't take into account what happens when you get passed a negative `int` which your new `struct` can't handle.

You will need to write the conversions yourself, I would take in the `int` as given, check if it's negative, check if it's bigger than 16777215, if it passes those checks then it's between 0 and 16777215 and you can store it in your new `struct`, simply execute a `Where(b => b != 0)` instead of `Take(3)` to get around the endian-ness problem. Obviously take into account the 0 case where all bytes = 0.